# flutter error : error when run the application after flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/story_viewer-0.2.0/lib/viewer.dart:274:43: Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.

- 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
- 'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
  borderRadius: widget.borderRadius as BorderRadius?,
  ^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture/page_view/gesture_page_view.dart:21:49: Error: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided.
  final PageMetrics _testPageMetrics = PageMetrics(
  ^
  ../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:266:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  PageMetrics({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture/page_view/widgets/scroll_position.dart:213:15: Error: The method 'ExtendedPagePosition.copyWith' doesn't have the named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' of overridden method 'ViewportOffset with ScrollMetrics.copyWith'.
  PageMetrics copyWith({
  ^
  ../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:178:16: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
  abstract class ScrollPosition extends ViewportOffset with ScrollMetrics {
  ^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture/page_view/widgets/scroll_position.dart:213:15: Error: The method 'ExtendedPagePosition.copyWith' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'PageMetrics.copyWith'.
  PageMetrics copyWith({
  ^
  ../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:277:15: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
  PageMetrics copyWith({
  ^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture/page_view/widgets/scroll_position.dart:213:15: Error: The method 'ExtendedPagePosition.copyWith' doesn't have the named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' of overridden method 'PageMetrics.copyWith'.
  PageMetrics copyWith({
  ^
  ../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:277:15: Context: This is the overridden method ('copyWith').
  PageMetrics copyWith({
  ^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture/page_view/widgets/scroll_position.dart:221:23: Error: Required named parameter 'devicePixelRatio' must be provided.
  return PageMetrics(
  ^
  ../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:266:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  PageMetrics({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/gesture_detector/drag.dart:145:3: Error: The superclass, 'OneSequenceGestureRecognizer', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
  ExtendedDragGestureRecognizer({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image-6.4.1/lib/src/extended_image.dart:975:36: Error: The argument type 'BorderRadius?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BorderRadiusGeometry' because 'BorderRadius?' is nullable and 'BorderRadiusGeometry' isn't.
- 'BorderRadius' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
- 'BorderRadiusGeometry' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/border_radius.dart' ('../../FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/border_radius.dart').
  borderRadius: widget.borderRadius,
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/sharsad/Documents/Applications/FlutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/sharsad/Documents/Applications/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.
all dependencies are up-to-date.